# Description of $(T\Bbb{CP}^1)^\perp$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Is there a nice "concrete" description (i.e., coordinates) of the normal bundle of $\Bbb{CP}^1$ when is considered as a submanifold of $\Bbb{CP}^n$? Or, at least, $\Bbb{CP}^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}\newcommand{\CP}{\mathbf{CP}}$Yes, it's a direct sum of $(n - 1)$ copies of the hyperplane bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\CP^{1}}(1)$.

In fact, the total space of this bundle embeds holomorphically in $\CP^{n}$; the image is the complement of a linear subspace of dimension $(n - 2)$ disjoint from $\CP^{1}$. This is particularly easy to see in $\CP^{2}$: Pick a point not in $\CP^{1}$, and project away from it. The fibres of the projection are complex lines transverse to $\CP^{1}$.

In $\CP^{n}$ with $n \geq 2$, project away from a skew $(n - 2)$-dimensional subspace $P$; that is, if $x$ is a point of $\CP^{n} \setminus P$, the hyperplane containing $x$ and $P$ intersects $\CP^{1}$ at a unique point $\pi(x)$; the mapping $\pi:\CP^{n} \setminus P \to \CP^{1}$ is the projection of the normal bundle.

---

**Edit** to add requested details:

Geometrically, choose projectively independent points $(a_{j})_{j=1}^{n-1}$ in the $(n - 2)$-dimensional subspace $P$, i.e., $(n - 1)$ points represented by some basis of the $(n - 1)$-dimensional vector subspace of $\Cpx^{n+1}$ whose projectivization is $P$. For each point $b$ of $\CP^{1}$, the $(n - 1)$ lines $\ell_{j}(b) = \overline{a_{j}b}$ span the projective hyperplane containing $P$ and $b$, whose intersection with $\CP^{n} \setminus P$ is the fibre $\pi^{-1}(b)$. As $b$ varies over $\CP^{1}$, the lines $\ell_{j}(b)$ sweep out the projective plane containing $\CP^{1}$ and $a_{j}$, the total space of a hyperplane bundle over $\CP^{1}$ (with the point $a_{j}$ at infinity).

Algebraically, after a linear change of coordinates we may assume (as in my second comment below) that $[z_{0}: z_{1}: \dots: z_{n}]$ are homogeneous coordinates on $\CP^{n}$, that $\CP^{1}$ is defined by $z_{j} =0$ for $2 \leq j \leq n$, and that $P$ is defined by $z_{0} = z_{1} = 0$. Projection away from $P$ is then the coordinate projection
$$
\pi\bigl([z_{0}: z_{1}: z_{2}: \dots: z_{n}]\bigr) = [z_{0}: z_{1}: 0: \dots: 0].
$$
The normal bundle of $\CP^{1}$ in $\CP^{n}$ is the direct sum of the $z_{j}$-coordinate axes for $2 \leq j \leq n$, each of which is a hyperplane bundle over $\CP^{1}$. (In this second description, $a_{j}$ is the point of $\CP^{n}$ corresponding to the $j$th standard basis vector.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you know a book with these kinds of things?

Comment: @user233339: You're welcome. :) Griffiths and Harris is one possibility, but I recall gleaning a lot of these factlets here and there. (Having an encyclopedic advisor helped.) There are a number of new (published since 2000) books on complex geometry, so there may well be good references I don't know of....

Comment: Thanks again. I'll have a look. :)

Comment: @user233339: I neglected to mention: If $[z_{0} : z_{1} : \dots : z_{n}]$ are homogeneous coordinates on $\mathbf{CP}^{n}$, if $\mathbf{CP}^{1}$ "sits in the first two coordinates" (i.e., is defined by $z_{2} = \dots = z_{n} = 0$), and if $P = \{z_{0} = z_{1} = 0\}$, then the projection away from $P$ is the "obvious" coordinate projection $$[z_{0} : z_{1} : z_{2} : \dots : z_{n}] \mapsto [z_{0} : z_{1} : 0 : \dots : 0] \sim [z_{0} : z_{1}].$$(Note that this fails to make sense precisely along $P$.)

Comment: Dear Andrew, this is a very beautiful  geometric construction. Could you however add some details/computations  leading to a rigorous proof ? My idea would be to choose projectively  independant points $ a_1,...,a_{n-1}\in P$ which joined to  some point $b\in \mathbb P^1$ would give  $n-1$ independant lines in the normal vector space to $\mathbb P^1$ at $b$.